# How to display text with certain Images using Ajax and Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've been trying to find a way to show certain text files using jQuery and Ajax.

A txt file should show up when a certain image is displaying. For example, if a picture of an apple is showing i want text under it saying "Apple" and if a picture of a Banana is showing then i want the text to say "Banana" and etc.

I am using a an array to pick the random pictures to display, but i can't figure out how to then show the text under it.

Here is my image-displaying code:

```
function displayPic() {    
    var imagesArray1 = new Array();

    imagesArray1 = [
        "img/Banana.jpeg", "img/Banana1.jpg", "img/Banana2.jpg",
        "img/Apple.jpg","img/Apple1.jpg", "img/Apple2.jpg"
    ]

    var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray1.length);
    var img1 = imagesArray1[num1];

    $("#picture").attr("src", img1);
}
```

So I want the corresponding txt file to show with the image that is being displayed. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: One way is to get the name of the image as a `string` (which you have, in `img1`), then find out if that string `contains` (or has a `substring`) apple, or banana, `then` based on that result, get the appropriate text and show it.

Comment: Are you withholding some information from us? You said you wanted to show "show certain text files". Where do you define these text files? In your post I can only see an array with image file names.

Comment: @cars10m if we have all the information, then the only option is to use the image names. This assumes images _always_ include the name of the picture it's going to show (Banana image is named *banana*) and without typos. Many ways to do it, for instances `var str = "imagename";
var pos = str.search("banana"); (if -1, then it's not banana, so go and do the same for another fruit).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the array for an array of structs, then when you randomize the index you will have the image and the text.

Here's an example:

```js
function displayPic() {    
    var imagesArray1 = new Array();

    imagesArray1 = [
        {text: "Banana", img:"img/Banana.jpeg"},
        {text: "Banana", img:"img/Banana1.jpg"}, 
        {text: "Banana", img:"img/Banana2.jpg"},
        {text: "Apple", img:"img/Apple.jpg"},
        {text: "Apple", img:"img/Apple1.jpg"},
        {text: "Apple", img:"img/Apple2.jpg"}
    ]

    var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray1.length);
    var img1 = imagesArray1[num1].img;
    var text = imagesArray1[num1].text;

    //$("#picture").attr("src", img1);
    $("#img").html(img1);
    $("#text").html(text);
}

displayPic();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img"></div>
<div id="text"></div>
```